# how to create a new list from other list with filter Product_Type__c

Tags: list, opportunity-lineitem, data

I have a list of records which has a custom field as Product_Type__c.I want to make a new list with similar field type (Product_Type__c ) in one list.I have below list.I dont know how to filter such list of records to a new list.

```
(OpportunityLineItem:{Id=00k28000002dgTbAAI, OpportunityId=00628000004fmcYAAQ, Name=University of AZ Installations GenWatt Diesel 1000kW, ProductCode=GC1060, Quantity=1.00, TotalPrice=100000.00, UnitPrice=100000.00, Product_Type__c=Combined}, OpportunityLineItem:{Id=00k28000002dfjaAAA, OpportunityId=00628000004fmcYAAQ, Name=University of AZ Installations GenWatt Diesel 1000kW, ProductCode=GC1060, Quantity=1.00, TotalPrice=100000.00, UnitPrice=100000.00, Product_Type__c=Hardware}, OpportunityLineItem:{Id=00k28000002djJnAAI, OpportunityId=00628000004fmcYAAQ, Name=University of AZ Installations Installation: Industrial - High, ProductCode=IN7080, Quantity=3.00, TotalPrice=255000.00, UnitPrice=85000.00, Product_Type__c=Combined})
```

ProductPDFController:

```
public with sharing class ProductPDFController {
   // ID OpportunityId;
   public string renderAs{get;set;}
    public list<wrapProducts> wrapProductsList { get; set; }
    public list<OpportunityLineItem> selectedProducts{get;set;}
    List<OpportunityLineItem> pd1=new list<OpportunityLineItem>();
                   List<OpportunityLineItem> pd2=new list<OpportunityLineItem>();
                   List<OpportunityLineItem> pd3=new list<OpportunityLineItem>();
                   List<OpportunityLineItem> pd4=new list<OpportunityLineItem>();
                   List<OpportunityLineItem> pd5=new list<OpportunityLineItem>();


    ID OpportunityId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

    public ProductPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }


    public List<wrapProducts> getList() 
    {
    wrapProductsList=new list<wrapProducts>();

    List<OpportunityLineItem> prolist= Database.Query('Select id,Opportunity.Name,Name,ProductCode,Quantity,TotalPrice,UnitPrice,Product_Type__c from OpportunityLineitem WHERE Opportunity.Id=:OpportunityId');         
    for(OpportunityLineItem pr1:prolist){
               wrapProductsList.add(new wrapProducts(pr1));  
            }
    return wrapProductsList;
    }
        public PageReference CancelRecords() {
        PageReference pageref=new PageReference('/'+OpportunityId); 
                return pageref;
        }


        public PageReference saveRecords() {
        selectedProducts=new list<OpportunityLineItem>();
        Pagereference pageref = page.pdfPage;
        pageref.setRedirect(true);
        for(wrapProducts wrappro:wrapProductsList){
           if(wrappro.isSelected==true){
           selectedProducts.add(wrappro.pr);
               System.debug('value of page :::: '+wrappro.pr);
                System.debug('value of selectedProducts1 :::: '+selectedProducts);
               Integer type1 = 0;
               Integer type2 = 0;
               Integer type3 = 0;
               Integer type4 = 0;
               Integer type5 = 0;
               for(OpportunityLineItem spdt:selectedProducts ){
                   System.debug('value of selectedProducts2 :::: '+selectedProducts);

                   if(spdt.Product_Type__c =='Combined') {
                       type1 = type1 + 1;
                       pd1.add(spdt);
                       System.debug('value of type1 :::: '+type1);
                       System.debug('value of pd1 :::: '+pd1);
                   }else if(spdt.Product_Type__c =='Hardware'){
                       type2 = type2 + 1;
                       pd2.add(spdt);
                       System.debug('value of type2 :::: '+type2);
                       System.debug('value of pd2 :::: '+pd2);
                   }else if(spdt.Product_Type__c =='Programming'){
                       type3 = type3 + 1;
                       pd3.add(spdt);
                       System.debug('value of type3 :::: '+type3);
                       System.debug('value of pd3 :::: '+pd3);
                   }else if(spdt.Product_Type__c =='Software'){
                       type4 = type4 + 1;
                       pd4.add(spdt);
                       System.debug('value of type4 :::: '+type4);
                       System.debug('value of pd4 :::: '+pd4);
                   }else{
                       type5 = type5 + 1;
                       pd5.add(spdt);
                       System.debug('value of pd5 :::: '+pd5);
                   }


               }

           pageref.getParameters().put('id',wrappro.pr.OpportunityId);
               doCheckNumerOfPDF(type1,type2,type3,type4,type5); 
           } 

         }

        return pageref;

        }

    public class wrapProducts{

    public OpportunityLineItem pr{get;set;}
    public boolean isSelected{get;set;}

       public wrapProducts(OpportunityLineItem p){

         pr=p;
         isselected=false;
       }
  }
    public void doCheckNumerOfPDF(Integer i,Integer j,Integer k,Integer l,Integer m){
        System.debug('value of doCheckNumerOfPDF1 :::::: '+i);
        System.debug('value of doCheckNumerOfPDF2 :::::: '+j);
        System.debug('value of doCheckNumerOfPDF3 :::::: '+k);
        System.debug('value of doCheckNumerOfPDF4 :::::: '+l);
        System.debug('value of doCheckNumerOfPDF5 :::::: '+m);
        //System.debug('value of doCheckNumerOfPDF5 :::::: '+t); 
        if(i!= 0){
            pdf1();
        }else if(j!=0){
            pdf2();
        }else if(k!=0){
            pdf3();
        }else if(l!=0){
            pdf4();
        }else {
            pdf5(); 
        }

    }
    public PageReference pdf1(){
    Pagereference pageref = page.pdfPage1;
    pageref.setRedirect(true);
    System.debug('value of pd1 in page ?????? '+pd1);    
    //pageref.getParameters().put('id',pd1.OpportunityId);
    return pageref;
    }

    public PageReference pdf2(){

    return null;
    }

    public PageReference pdf3(){

    return null;
    }

    public PageReference pdf4(){

    return null;
    }

    public PageReference pdf5(){

    return null;
    }

}
```

If you see in the above sample 2 records belong to same Product_Type__c i.e "Combined".So i want these 2 records to be put in one list and other record with Product_type__c as hardware to be in other list.I am just trying for 1 page.If it works then i implement for pdf2,pdf3 etc

Answer (score 0):

Robert,

you need to iterate over results to put them in different list as shown below

```
List<OpporutnityLineItem> lstHardware = new List<Opporutnitylineitem()
List<OpporutnityLineItem> lstCombined = new List<Opporutnitylineitem>();

for(Opporutnitylineitem oli : youropplineitemvariable)
{
     //if it is equal to compbined
    if(oli.Product_Type__c=='Combined')
       lstCombined.add(oli);

     //if it is equal to hardware
    if(oli.Product_Type__c=='Hardware')
        lstHardware.add(oli);
}
```

Comment: I did the same but i am getting repeated item in one list.I am basically using wrapper class and making a selection for records.I will paste my code here.If you can check where i am going wrong.

Comment: if you have have repeated items it is better to go for Map.